# Circuit or Equipment to delay high speed square clock signal?

Tags: filter, delay, phase, schmitt-trigger, test-equipment

Hi I have a ttl clock signal that id like to change the phase of to see if it changes effects the unit under test (not relevant but its a digital transmitter and an automated testing setup) this way I can see if longer bnc cables would cause issues (because of how it changes phase). What sort of circuit would I need to make or what equipment would I need to buy to achieve this? It is fairly fast like 50 MB/S.

Comment: Hm.. Two cascaded inverters?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Two cascaded inverters with RC in between. With variable trimmer capacitor...

Comment: Group Delay is defined by an All pass filter order or a low pass filter with limiter.  How many cycles or time delay ? Is it the enable gate or just phase or signal impedance that could be a problem?

Comment: The sandwiched RC/inverters circuit gets my vote. I was looking for something to phase shift a square wave, this works brilliantly. For even more phase shift you can cascade multiples of this and for voltage or digital control replace R with VCA or MDACs....

Answer (score 2):

Consider a **programmable delay line** or **programmable timing element**. These are ICs which can apply delays to a clock signal, and can be controlled by a microcontroller to vary they delay they apply.

You will need to choose a chip based on the delay range and resolution you need, but to give an example, the Maxim [DS1124](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1124.pdf) would be suitable for 10MHz clock signals, and con be programmed over SPI.